# Google Drive - How do I find who a document is shared with?

Tags: .net, google-drive-api

Using the Google Drive API I can get all files from Google Drive. I can see who owns the file, but what I can't figure out is how I see who a certain file is shared with. I can see that the Shared property is true, but not to who. The Permissions List only returns permissions for the owner of the file.

In the Google Document List API one was able to do this by means of Access Control Lists. What is the way one is supposed to do it today? (I don't want to use the old deprecated Document List API).

Anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I had misunderstood Google Drive a bit. If I switch the user of the service account to the user who owns the file, I can get all the relevant info. I thought I could get it as the administrator.

Answer (score 1):

You can view permissions on a file with the Drive API but you have to make a call to do so.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/list

You can see examples of how to execute this API method for various coding languages to get a permissions resource returned that shows the list of users with access and their role on the file in question.

So in essence, you would have to get the list of files, then cycle through that list and gather the permissions resource per each file id.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know, the problem is, as I wrote above, that I only get the owner - no shares!

Answer (score 0):

Users who have view access can not see the permissions of a file other than the owner.

Comment: I'm using a service account, using the super administrator credentials, and I am using the full Drive scope. Shouldn't I have these rights?

Comment: Further investigation shows that I can see permissions for some files, and not for others. File1: Only the owner is shown after using Permissions.List for the file. Using the Google Drive UI, I'm included in the share list. File2: I can see myself in the Permissions.List through the API and through the Google Drive UI. Are there certain conditions on Google Drive that creates this difference?